# Difficulties solving Cipher Riddle of an ARG

Tags: riddle, cipher, alternate-reality-game

I got the following from an ARG (alternate reality game) website called terminal00:

```
Msp  n.rf  rmu.pbq  rfc  rpsrfyyy  gr  f.u  ,ccI  ,jmuI  .u.wz    q.kc  .q  kw  umpbqy
Rfc  ugIbyyy  ir  gq  ecrrgIe  qrpmIecpy
,rq  F  ´.k  j.hb  Irq  fqp  qo.´bpxxx  Vbpy  qebobyp  pIjbqefkd  qeboby  .iIkd  qeb  tfkapx
Qeb  qtI  ´roobkqpy  qebvyob  gIfkfkdxxx
Jfqqckz  qfbpb  .oc  ksj,bcoqxyx  Wbqxyx  recoc  .pb  Irk´coq  qfbpb.  .  aIbbz  mcof.np?
Ecocb  Gzji  n.qp  gq  .imke  qm  vmry
Ehybo/  Qfvy  Mkcy  XbpIz  Kgkcy  LfIbz  Cmrpx  wkjb
```

The original html-comment clue:

```
<!--Msp n.rf bccncpyyy gr f.u ,ccl ,jmul .u.wz q.kc .q kw umpbqy-->
```

It looks like it uses some sort of ROT2, ROT3 shift to encode the first 1-2 and 3-4 lines respectively. The last three lines contain letters that repeat, indicating there is some sort of mono-alphabetic cipher. The solution should be a URL or part of a URL. The rest I know is speculative.

EDIT: Added the html-comment clue

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/codes/comments/85ed8t/cipher_riddle/

Comment: @somebody that is my post. I wanted to keep things free from my assumptions. Nonetheless I'm stuck at the same place where other have too (so far).

Comment: @SimpleMath well your assumptions so far look completely accurate, we just need to find out what to do from there. e.g. the `/` looks kinda suspicious, and so does the last line with all those 4/5 letter words)

Comment: Thanks to Pex_Juv on reddit we now know that there is an elliptical rot cipher. That is changing the rot between 2 and 3 for each letter.

Comment: Should there be an exact link ciphered to go to? In that case, are there any examples of already used links of the game (previous rounds, maybe)?

Comment: @ThomasBlue From what I can gather there is no real consistency here. The riddle on the page 00_Dark has a solution that translates to binary and gives us the full answer. Then the following riddle on that page gives us only "_Gets_Longer" which needs to be appended. Here the numbers are part of something ( which and that is not stated or is not deciphered ). Then there are "riddles" that depend on seeing links that are meant to be added to the root path of the webserver. So the best format guess would be: First the numbers, then numbers in combination with something.

Comment: There is a probability that the one and only solution to the puzzle is a png located under /images/610994.png.

Answer (score 5):

As you stated, ROT2 and ROT3 help a little bit

ROT2:

> Our  p.th  tow.rds  the  truthaaa  it  h.w  ,eeK  ,lowK  .w.yb  s.me  .s  my  wordsa
> The  wiKdaaa  kt  is  gettiKg  stroKgera
> ,ts  H  ´.m  l.jd  Kts hsr  sq.´drzzz  Xdra  sgdqdar  rKldsghmf  sgdqda  .kKmf  sgd  vhmcrz
> Sgd  svK  ´tqqdmsra  sgdxaqd  iKhmhmfzzz

ROT3:

> Pvs  q.ui  upx.set  uif  usvuibbb  ju  i.x  ,ffL  ,mpxL  .x.zc  t.nf  .t  nz  xpsetb 
>  Uif  xjLebbb  lu  jt  hfuujLh  tuspLhfsb 
> ,ut  I  ´.n  m.ke  Lut  its  tr.´esaaa  Yesb  therebs  sLmething  thereb  .lLng  the  windsa 
>  The  twL  ´urrentsb  theybre  jLiningaaa

Mixing them together give us:

> Our  p.th  tow.rds  the  truth  it  h.w  ,eeK  ,lowK  .w.y  s.me  .s  my  words
>  The  wiKd  kt  is  gettiKg  stroKger
>  ,ut  I  ´.n  m.ke  Lut  its  tr.´es  Yes  theres  sLmething  there  .lLng  the  winds
>  The  twL  ´urrents  theyre  jLining

The next step is replacing some letters with each others :

> K => n 
>  L => o 
>  ´=> c 
>  .=>a 
>  ,=>b

this give us:

> Our  path  towards  the  truth  it  haw  been  blown  away  same  as  my  words 
>  The  wind  kt  is  getting  stronger 
>  but  I  can  make  out  its  traces  Yes  theres  something  there  along  the  winds 
>  The  two  currents  theyre  joining

but that doesn't work for the last lines, must be another encryption

Comment: The letters are replaced with the character three chars up

Answer (score 2):

Robert Garrett have already posted a similar answer on reddit. However, he didn't explain how he got it.

> After a while it becomes *obvious* that letter 'I' in the original code is actually 'l' lost during some data operation. So, we replace it as is.

Now for the first part.

> Let's imagine it's all a single code, without any stretches. Then (as we have seen rot-2 approximation) '.' is definitely 'a' and 'y' is definitely '.'. Why is so? Well, my assumption is, the rotation wheel contains not only alphabet, but also punctuation. Basing on found terms, the wheel is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,", giving us, as it is: 
>  Our path towards the truth... it ha**w** been blown away, same as my words.  
>  The wind... **k**t is getting stronger.

That's as close as I can get, while remaining logical. As for the second part,

> The rotation wheel becomes 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,'', with apostrophe. Why? Either to confuse us, or to add the apostrophe in the process. Or, maybe, we still want 'a' to be '.'. With that and rot-3, the string transforms to 
>  But I can make out its traces... Yes, there,s something there, along the winds. 
>  The two currents, they,re joining... 
>  
>  While I tried to find explanation for these mistakes, I still see none - no modified cipher, for instance. Perhaps, it's one of your fancy code inside a code thing - and mistakes actully mean something else. I don't know.

Now the third code is a mix of first to 'rot'-s. Probably. I'll show you how I applied it:

> "222 2222 2222222 222 22222222 22 222 2222 22222 22222 2222 22 22 222222",
> "222 2222222 22 22 2222222 222222222",
> "333 3 333 3333 333 333 333333333 3333 3333333 333333333 333333 33333 333 333333",
> "333 333 333333333 3333333 3333333333",
> "2323232 32323 232 32323232323 232323 23232 323 2323232 323232 3 23232 3232323?",
> "32323 2323 2323 23 23232 32 3232",
> "32323/ 2323 2323 23232 32323 23232 32323 2323" 
>  Codes are changed each letter, without taking spaces into account - so I believe, the last '/' sign is not taken into account. Anyway, that didn't give me a lot.

This is what a result looks like:

> Listen, there are numb**ee**rs... Yes... there are num**c**ers there**a** a code, perhaps? 
>  Her**ee** I´ll pass it along to you. 
>  **Hj,dr/** Six, One, Zero, Nine, Nine, Four. **ynle**

Now, the last string again, in two rot-s:

> Gj.dq/ Shx. Ome. Zdrn, Mime. Nhnd, Eotrz ymld 
> Hk,er/ Tiy, Pnf, .eso´ Njnf, Oioe´ Fpus. znme 
>  in case you want to find a meaningful combination.

And the whole thing:

> *Our path towards the truth... it haw been blown away, same as my words.* 
> *The wind... kt is getting stronger.*
> *but I can make out its traces...*
> *Yes, there,s something there, along the winds.*
> *The two currents, they,re joining...*
> *Listen, there are numbeers... Yes... there are numcers therea a code, perhaps?*
> *Heree I´ll pass it along to you.*
> *Hj,dr/ Six, One, Zero, Nine, Nine, Four. ynle*

Comment: I do see the imperfections / confusions as mistakes from the puzzle-creators side. The puzzle has no consistency behind it and is rather random in nature and badly executed. It is more tedious guesswork then actual problem solving. It seems to me that the author makes the assumption that the function used and the searched inverse function are actually easy to find even without the key.

Comment: I have granted you the bounty even though it does not contain the fully decoded message it is a step closer then the most upvoted post at the time of writing this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Puttting Rot2 seems to give you this following solution:

> Our  p.th  tow.rds  the  truthaaa  it  h.w  ,eeK  ,lowK  .w.yb    s.me    .s my  wordsa 
>  The  wiKdaaa  kt  is  gettiKg  stroKgera 
>  ,ts  H  ´.m  l.jd  Kts  hsr  sq.´drzzz  Xdra  sgdqdar  rKldsghmf  sgdqda  .kKmf  sgd  vhmcrz 
>  Sgd  svK  ´tqqdmsra  sgdxaqd  iKhmhmfzzz 
>  Lhssemb  shdrd  .qe  mul,deqszaz  Ydszaz  tgeqe  .rd  Ktm´eqs  shdrd.  .  cKddb  oeqh.pr? 
>  Geqed  Iblk  p.sr  is  .komg  so  xota 
>  Gjadq/  Shxa  Omea  ZdrKb  Mimea  NhKdb  Eotrz  ymld

Comment: Whoops my spoiler is not working

Comment: Using return for line breaks breaks the spoilers, try using <br> instead

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman ... please use two spaces instead because that's the sane thing to do

Comment: @Somebody, I find two spaces hard to track during edits personally, but yes that also works.